# I got ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to unknown command

Tags: android-emulator, webdriver-io, appium-android

Error message displayed :
`ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

> ERROR webdriver: unknown command: The requested resource could not be found, or a request was received using an HTTP method that is not supported by the mapped resource

`
wdio.conf.js file:

**let { join } = require('path');
exports.config = {
port: 4723, // default appium port
services: [
['appium', {
command : 'appium'
}]
],

```
specs: [
    './test/specs/**/*.js'
],

maxInstances: 10,
capabilities: [{
    platformName:'Android',
    platformVersion:'9',
    deviceName:'Pixel',
    app:'D:/test/appium/test2/ApiDemos-debug.apk',   

bail: 0,   
baseUrl: 'http://localhost',    
waitforTimeout: 60000,    
connectionRetryTimeout: 120000,   
connectionRetryCount: 3, 

framework: 'mocha',
```

}**

package.json file:
**
{

"name": "test2",

"version": "1.0.0",

"description": "",

"main": "index.js",

"scripts": {

```
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/wdio wdio.conf.js"
```

},

"keywords": [],

"author": "",

"license": "ISC",

"dependencies": {

```
"@wdio/cli": "^7.3.1",

"appium": "^1.20.2"
```

},

"devDependencies": {

```
"@wdio/appium-service": "^7.4.2",

"@wdio/local-runner": "^7.3.1",

"@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.3.1",

"@wdio/selenium-standalone-service": "^7.3.1",

"@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.3.1",

"@wdio/sync": "^7.3.1",

"chromedriver": "^89.0.0",

"wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.0.0"
```

}

}**

Answer (score 7):

Run this in the commandline to start the appium

```
appium --base-path /wd/hub
```

And make sure that the "Remote Path" in your Appium inspector is

```
/wd/hub
```

Answer (score 6):

Add path: '/wd/hub/' in config file.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried. it works.
you need add /wd/hub on your base URL
baseUrl: 'http://localhost/wd/hub'

also, you need to start appium server with the command below

appium --base-path /wd/hub